# Присваивание большого начального значения при расчёте минимума

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Что можно сделать, чтобы не присваивать `min_num = 99999999;`? Как правильнее это сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int all_num;
    float num, sum = 0, max_num = 0, min_num = 99999999;
    cout << "Введите количество чисел\n";
    cin >> all_num;
    for (int i = 1; i <= all_num; ++i) {
        cout << "Введите " << i << " число\n";
        cin >> num;
        if (max_num <= num) max_num = num;          
        if (min_num >= num) min_num = num;
        sum += num;
    }
    cout << "Avg = " << sum / all_num << endl;
    cout << "Max = " << max_num << endl;
    cout << "Min = " << min_num << endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Так *"не присваивать"* или *"правильнее сделать"*?

Comment: Думаю что сделать правильно это и будет не присваивать такое значение. ;)

Comment: Ну не присваивайте...

Comment: Тогда работать ничего не будет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, например    `numeric_limits<float>::max()`

Но правильнее - присвоить первое значение в последовательности и минимуму, и максимуму. А потом работать с остальными точно так же, как и ранее...

Comment: Почему не стоит использовать #include "pch.h" ? Visual Studio без этой строки не хочет компилировать проект.

Comment: Потому что она привязывает к конкретно Visual Studio. А у вас вопрос по С++, а не по Visual'у. Это всего лишь заголовок при включенной предкомпиляции - которую можно спокойно отключить, и будет VS компилировать все, как миленький... Точно так же я убрал бы если бы он тут был) `windows.h`, потому что код к конкретной операционной системе не привязан. Впрочем, соглашусь - это уже дело вкуса, конечно...